# how to fix error in installing vue in Laravel project

Tags: laravel, vue.js

going to install vue as using following commnd `npm init vite vue` in a laravel project. but when I try it got following error message in my terminal

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:140:18)
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path F:\2022\Laravel + Vue\laravel-vue-survey
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-vite "vue"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Nalaka\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-20T06_31_44_838Z-debug-0.log
PS F:\2022\Laravel + Vue\laravel-vue-survey> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

how could I fix it?

Comment: Show your vite config. Clear your npm cache, the error might be in your vite config. Fix the error, then try again

Comment: @UnderDog how could I find vite config in package.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading node. I bet its an older version

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to initialize a `Vue` project with Vite. For that you should use the `vite create` instead of `npm init`.

```
vite create project-name vue
```